# Parse PowerShell command line arguments on a module load

Tags: powershell

I'm building a PowerShell module and I'd like to get the command line arguments from the main script parsed when module gets loaded.

Any ideas on how to do that? I have checked that $args has values on the mains script, but not on the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to a module using the ArgumentList parameter (of Import-Module) and check for $args in the psm1 file

Answer (score 0):

I found it: pass the arguments along using -ArgumentList

Import-Module .\module.psm1 -ArgumentList $args